# how to separate coma in json result ( React Js)

Tags: json, reactjs

i want to separate coma in JSON result and use in my React JS

this the
JSON output :

```
 "photo" :"[\"photo1\",\"photo2\",\"photo3\",\"photo4\"]"
```

i use react js with API to get result above, but the result i want is :

"link + photo1"

"link + photo2"

"link + photo3"

.

what should i do to get result that i want?
i already write this code, but doesn't work

```
 var link = "http://photo..."
  const { photo} = post;

        var getphoto = JSON.parse(photo.split('));
```

and in return i write

```
       <img src={link + getphoto} alt={getphoto} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly `parse()` would be fine, it would become an Array.

Adjust each item using map()

```js
const link = "http://photo..."
const data = "[\"photo1\",\"photo2\",\"photo3\",\"photo4\"]";

const result = JSON.parse(data).map(x => link + x);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: if i want to add link in front of every photo, what should code i write?